# Laravel reverse a collection hierarchy

Tags: php, laravel

Say I have a collection that looks like this:

```php
$subscriptions = collect([
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "event" => "FormCompleted",
        "subscriber" => [
            "id" => 2929,
            "name" => "Adam",
            "email" => "adam@dude.com"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "event" => "FormCompleted",
        "subscriber" => [
            "id" => 1928,
            "name" => "Pope",
            "email" => "pope@dude.com"
        ], 
    ],
    [
        "id" => 4,
        "event" => "StatusChanged",
        "subscriber" => [
            "id" => 2929,
            "name" => "Adam",
            "email" => "adam@dude.com"
        ]
    ]
]);
```

This shows a list of **events with its subscriber**. What I want is to re-group this to show a list of **subscribers with its events**. How do I group these results to get a result like this?

```
[
    [
        "id" => 2929,
        "name" => "Adam",
        "email" => "adam@dude.com",
        "subscriptions" => [
            [
                "id" => 1,
                "event" => "FormCompleted"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 4,
                "event" => "StatusChanged"
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1928,
        "name" => "Pope",
        "email" => "pope@dude.com",
        "subscriptions" => [
            [
                "id" => 3,
                "event" => "FormCompleted"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here is my code... which works, but it is very messy and I feel like there is a better way to do it...

```
$subscribers = $subscriptions->groupBy('subscriber.id')
    ->map(function($group) {
        $subscriber = $group[0]->subscriber;
        $subscriber['subscriptions'] = $group->map(function($subscription) {
            unset($subscription['subscriber']);
            return $subscription;
        });
        return $subscriber;
    })->values();
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to do this at the point where you get the collection, instead of trying to alter the collection after the fact.

Answer (score -1):

I think like that this should return you all subscribers who have groups, so guarantees return not empty subscribers with events
More details you can read [this in documention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```php
return Subscriber::has('groups')->get()->groupBy('id');
```